# track text in switch button

Tags: java, android, button

Please, somebody knows how I can set text in track part of switch button, I need to do this whith java code not with xml code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvyBb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for Android switch buttons you may use the following:

```
//sets text on creation
toggleButton.setText(textOff);

// Sets the text for when the button off.
toggleButton.setTextOff(textOff);

// Sets the text for when the button is on.
toggleButton.setTextOn(textOn);
```

Comment: Yes for android, this answer is for thumb text but I'm searching the way to add text in track part of switch button.